# ACPI errors after kernel 5.17.9 update

Tags: boot, kernel, updates, acpi

I've updated my kernel from 5.15 to 5.17.9 by installing the `.deb` packages from the kernel-ppa. After the boot screen I get ACPI errors and some peripherals like wifi won't work.
Here is the full dmesg

```
[    0.036755] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
[    0.036756] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009f000-0x000fffff]
[    0.036758] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x2de32000-0x2de32fff]
[    0.036759] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x2debf000-0x2ded2fff]
[    0.036760] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x3f4ff000-0x43ccefff]
[    0.036761] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x43ccf000-0x44abefff]
[    0.036761] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x44abf000-0x44bfefff]
[    0.036762] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x44c00000-0x48ffffff]
[    0.036763] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x49000000-0x49dfffff]
[    0.036764] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x49e00000-0x4f7fffff]
[    0.036764] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x4f800000-0xbfffffff]
[    0.036765] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff]
[    0.036765] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd0000000-0xfe00ffff]
[    0.036766] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfe010000-0xfe010fff]
[    0.036766] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfe011000-0xfed1ffff]
[    0.036767] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed20000-0xfed7ffff]
[    0.036767] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfed80000-0xff4fffff]
[    0.036768] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xff500000-0xffffffff]
[    0.036769] [mem 0x4f800000-0xbfffffff] available for PCI devices
[    0.036770] Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
[    0.036772] clocksource: refined-jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645519600211568 ns
[    0.036777] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:8192 nr_cpumask_bits:8 nr_cpu_ids:8 nr_node_ids:1
[    0.036916] percpu: Embedded 61 pages/cpu s212992 r8192 d28672 u262144
[    0.036922] pcpu-alloc: s212992 r8192 d28672 u262144 alloc=1*2097152
[    0.036923] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
[    0.036943] Fallback order for Node 0: 0 
[    0.036945] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 4063244
[    0.036946] Policy zone: Normal
[    0.036947] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.17.9-051709-generic root=UUID=09ca2cc6-adaf-4468-b5d2-27c3991501cb ro quiet splash quiet splash
[    0.037009] Unknown kernel command line parameters "splash splash BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.17.9-051709-generic", will be passed to user space.
[    0.037492] Dentry cache hash table entries: 2097152 (order: 12, 16777216 bytes, linear)
[    0.037738] Inode-cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes, linear)
[    0.037807] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
[    0.067786] Memory: 15974096K/16511608K available (16392K kernel code, 4476K rwdata, 10904K rodata, 2772K init, 4884K bss, 537252K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.067790] random: get_random_u64 called from kmem_cache_open+0x2b/0x360 with crng_init=1
[    0.067914] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=8, Nodes=1
[    0.067923] ftrace: allocating 51093 entries in 200 pages
[    0.074423] ftrace: allocated 200 pages with 3 groups
[    0.075018] Dynamic Preempt: voluntary
[    0.075040] rcu: Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.075040] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=8192 to nr_cpu_ids=8.
[    0.075041]  Trampoline variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.075042]  Rude variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.075042]  Tracing variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.075042] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
[    0.075043] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=8
[    0.077428] NR_IRQS: 524544, nr_irqs: 2048, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.077880] random: crng init done (trusting CPU's manufacturer)
[    0.077901] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[    0.077913] printk: console [tty0] enabled
[    0.077926] ACPI: Core revision 20211217
[    0.078185] hpet: HPET dysfunctional in PC10. Force disabled.
[    0.078186] APIC: Switch to symmetric I/O mode setup
[    0.078188] DMAR: Host address width 39
[    0.078189] DMAR: DRHD base: 0x000000fed90000 flags: 0x0
[    0.078193] DMAR: dmar0: reg_base_addr fed90000 ver 4:0 cap 1c0000c40660462 ecap 29a00f0505e
[    0.078195] DMAR: DRHD base: 0x000000fed91000 flags: 0x1
[    0.078196] DMAR: dmar1: reg_base_addr fed91000 ver 1:0 cap d2008c40660462 ecap f050da
[    0.078201] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x0000004b000000 end: 0x0000004f7fffff
[    0.078203] DMAR-IR: IOAPIC id 2 under DRHD base  0xfed91000 IOMMU 1
[    0.078204] DMAR-IR: HPET id 0 under DRHD base 0xfed91000
[    0.078205] DMAR-IR: Queued invalidation will be enabled to support x2apic and Intr-remapping.
[    0.079814] DMAR-IR: Enabled IRQ remapping in x2apic mode
[    0.079816] x2apic enabled
[    0.079844] Switched APIC routing to cluster x2apic.
[    0.084377] clocksource: tsc-early: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x28680fa287f, max_idle_ns: 440795281151 ns
[    0.084382] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 5606.40 BogoMIPS (lpj=11212800)
[    0.084384] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.085972] LSM: Security Framework initializing
[    0.085981] landlock: Up and running.
[    0.085982] Yama: becoming mindful.
[    0.086001] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
[    0.086039] Mount-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.086059] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.086223] CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1)
[    0.086225] x86/cpu: User Mode Instruction Prevention (UMIP) activated
[    0.086318] process: using mwait in idle threads
[    0.086320] Last level iTLB entries: 4KB 0, 2MB 0, 4MB 0
[    0.086320] Last level dTLB entries: 4KB 0, 2MB 0, 4MB 0, 1GB 0
[    0.086323] Spectre V1 : Mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
[    0.086325] Spectre V2 : Mitigation: Enhanced IBRS
[    0.086325] Spectre V2 : Spectre v2 / SpectreRSB mitigation: Filling RSB on context switch
[    0.086326] Spectre V2 : mitigation: Enabling conditional Indirect Branch Prediction Barrier
[    0.086327] Speculative Store Bypass: Mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
[    0.088379] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 40K
[    0.088379] smpboot: Estimated ratio of average max frequency by base frequency (times 1024): 1499
[    0.088379] smpboot: CPU0: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz (family: 0x6, model: 0x8c, stepping: 0x1)
[    0.088379] cblist_init_generic: Setting adjustable number of callback queues.
[    0.088379] cblist_init_generic: Setting shift to 3 and lim to 1.
[    0.088379] cblist_init_generic: Setting shift to 3 and lim to 1.
[    0.088379] cblist_init_generic: Setting shift to 3 and lim to 1.
[    0.088379] Performance Events: PEBS fmt4+-baseline,  AnyThread deprecated, Icelake events, 32-deep LBR, full-width counters, Intel PMU driver.
[    0.088379] ... version:                5
[    0.088379] ... bit width:              48
[    0.088379] ... generic registers:      8
[    0.088379] ... value mask:             0000ffffffffffff
[    0.088379] ... max period:             00007fffffffffff
[    0.088379] ... fixed-purpose events:   4
[    0.088379] ... event mask:             0001000f000000ff
[    0.088379] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.088379] NMI watchdog: Enabled. Permanently consumes one hw-PMU counter.
[    0.088379] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.088379] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[    0.088379] .... node  #0, CPUs:      #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 #7
[    0.093160] smp: Brought up 1 node, 8 CPUs
[    0.093160] smpboot: Max logical packages: 1
[    0.093160] smpboot: Total of 8 processors activated (44851.20 BogoMIPS)
[    0.096853] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.096853] x86/mm: Memory block size: 128MB
[    0.096977] ACPI: PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x43ccf000-0x44abefff] (14614528 bytes)
[    0.096977] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    0.096977] futex hash table entries: 2048 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.096977] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.096977] PM: RTC time: 14:02:26, date: 2022-05-21
[    0.096977] NET: Registered PF_NETLINK/PF_ROUTE protocol family
[    0.097064] DMA: preallocated 2048 KiB GFP_KERNEL pool for atomic allocations
[    0.097165] DMA: preallocated 2048 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA pool for atomic allocations
[    0.097268] DMA: preallocated 2048 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA32 pool for atomic allocations
[    0.097272] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.097276] audit: type=2000 audit(1653141746.012:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
[    0.097276] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'fair_share'
[    0.097276] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'bang_bang'
[    0.097276] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[    0.097276] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'user_space'
[    0.097276] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'power_allocator'
[    0.097276] EISA bus registered
[    0.097276] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.097276] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.097276] ACPI FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so disable it
[    0.097276] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.097276] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-ff] at [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] (base 0xc0000000)
[    0.097276] PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] reserved in E820
[    0.097276] PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
[    0.097276] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
[    0.097276] kprobes: kprobe jump-optimization is enabled. All kprobes are optimized if possible.
[    0.097276] HugeTLB registered 1.00 GiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.097276] HugeTLB registered 2.00 MiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.097276] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    0.097276] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    0.097276] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.097276] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.097276] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.097276] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.097276] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
[    0.156682] ACPI: 18 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[    0.157808] ACPI: EC: EC started
[    0.157808] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[    0.158981] ACPI: EC: EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x66, EC_DATA=0x62
[    0.158982] ACPI: EC: Boot ECDT EC used to handle transactions
[    0.166113] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.166123] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9F60C02B8800 0001C6 (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Psd  00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.166855] ACPI: \_SB_.PR00: _OSC native thermal LVT Acked
[    0.168803] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.168809] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9F60C127F000 000386 (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Cst  00003001 INTL 20160422)
[    0.169688] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.169693] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9F60C136C000 000647 (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Ist  00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.170654] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.170659] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9F60C127F800 00028B (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Hwp  00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.171687] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.171693] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9F60C0187000 0008E7 (v02 PmRef  ApIst    00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.172693] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.172697] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9F60C136A000 00048A (v02 PmRef  ApHwp    00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.173620] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.173625] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9F60C1368800 0004D4 (v02 PmRef  ApPsd    00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.174540] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.174545] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF9F60C1369800 00048A (v02 PmRef  ApCst    00003000 INTL 20160422)
[    0.178834] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.178874] ACPI: PM: (supports S0 S4 S5)
[    0.178874] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.178906] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.180552] ACPI: Enabled 7 GPEs in block 00 to 7F
[    0.181078] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [PCRP]
[    0.192963] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [V0PR]
[    0.193066] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [V1PR]
[    0.193165] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [V2PR]
[    0.197274] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [WRST]
[    0.202575] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [FN00]
[    0.202623] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [FN01]
[    0.202671] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [FN02]
[    0.202717] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [FN03]
[    0.202763] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [FN04]
[    0.203198] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [PIN]
[    0.203477] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PC00] (domain 0000 [bus 00-e0])
[    0.203481] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
[    0.206135] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability LTR]
[    0.206136] acpi PNP0A08:00: FADT indicates ASPM is unsupported, using BIOS configuration
[    0.208763] PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    0.208764] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0x0cf7 window]
[    0.208766] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0d00-0xffff window]
[    0.208767] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff window]
[    0.208767] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x4f800000-0xbfffffff window]
[    0.208768] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x4000000000-0x7fffffffff window]
[    0.208769] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-e0]
[    0.208862] pci 0000:00:00.0: [8086:9a14] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.208963] pci 0000:00:02.0: [8086:9a49] type 00 class 0x030000
[    0.208970] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x6002000000-0x6002ffffff 64bit]
[    0.208975] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0x4000000000-0x400fffffff 64bit pref]
[    0.208978] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x20: [io  0x5000-0x503f]
[    0.208991] pci 0000:00:02.0: BAR 2: assigned to efifb
[    0.208992] pci 0000:00:02.0: DMAR: Skip IOMMU disabling for graphics
[    0.208994] pci 0000:00:02.0: Video device with shadowed ROM at [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
[    0.209017] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x344: [mem 0x00000000-0x00ffffff 64bit]
[    0.209018] pci 0000:00:02.0: VF(n) BAR0 space: [mem 0x00000000-0x06ffffff 64bit] (contains BAR0 for 7 VFs)
[    0.209021] pci 0000:00:02.0: reg 0x34c: [mem 0x00000000-0x1fffffff 64bit pref]
[    0.209022] pci 0000:00:02.0: VF(n) BAR2 space: [mem 0x00000000-0xdfffffff 64bit pref] (contains BAR2 for 7 VFs)
[    0.209134] pci 0000:00:04.0: [8086:9a03] type 00 class 0x118000
[    0.209151] pci 0000:00:04.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x6003200000-0x600321ffff 64bit]
[    0.209384] pci 0000:00:08.0: [8086:9a11] type 00 class 0x088000
[    0.209392] pci 0000:00:08.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x600322f000-0x600322ffff 64bit]
[    0.209485] pci 0000:00:0e.0: [8086:9a0b] type 00 class 0x010400
[    0.209496] pci 0000:00:0e.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x6000000000-0x6001ffffff 64bit]
[    0.209502] pci 0000:00:0e.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0x50000000-0x51ffffff]
[    0.209514] pci 0000:00:0e.0: reg 0x20: [mem 0x6003100000-0x60031fffff 64bit]
[    0.209624] pci 0000:00:14.0: [8086:a0ed] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[    0.209645] pci 0000:00:14.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x52200000-0x5220ffff 64bit]
[    0.209729] pci 0000:00:14.0: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.210011] pci 0000:00:14.2: [8086:a0ef] type 00 class 0x050000
[    0.210033] pci 0000:00:14.2: reg 0x10: [mem 0x6003224000-0x6003227fff 64bit]
[    0.210048] pci 0000:00:14.2: reg 0x18: [mem 0x600322e000-0x600322efff 64bit]
[    0.210215] pci 0000:00:15.0: [8086:a0e8] type 00 class 0x0c8000
[    0.210243] pci 0000:00:15.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff 64bit]
[    0.210588] pci 0000:00:15.1: [8086:a0e9] type 00 class 0x0c8000
[    0.210615] pci 0000:00:15.1: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff 64bit]
[    0.210932] pci 0000:00:16.0: [8086:a0e0] type 00 class 0x078000
[    0.210956] pci 0000:00:16.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x600322b000-0x600322bfff 64bit]
[    0.211043] pci 0000:00:16.0: PME# supported from D3hot
[    0.211315] pci 0000:00:17.0: [8086:09ab] type 00 class 0x088000
[    0.211581] pci 0000:00:1d.0: [8086:a0b0] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.211677] pci 0000:00:1d.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.212127] pci 0000:00:1d.1: [8086:a0b1] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.212222] pci 0000:00:1d.1: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.212735] pci 0000:00:1e.0: [8086:a0a8] type 00 class 0x078000
[    0.212763] pci 0000:00:1e.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff 64bit]
[    0.213156] pci 0000:00:1e.3: [8086:a0ab] type 00 class 0x0c8000
[    0.213186] pci 0000:00:1e.3: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff 64bit]
[    0.213492] pci 0000:00:1f.0: [8086:a082] type 00 class 0x060100
[    0.213764] pci 0000:00:1f.3: [8086:a0c8] type 00 class 0x040100
[    0.213806] pci 0000:00:1f.3: reg 0x10: [mem 0x6003220000-0x6003223fff 64bit]
[    0.213861] pci 0000:00:1f.3: reg 0x20: [mem 0x6003000000-0x60030fffff 64bit]
[    0.213967] pci 0000:00:1f.3: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.214272] pci 0000:00:1f.4: [8086:a0a3] type 00 class 0x0c0500
[    0.214297] pci 0000:00:1f.4: reg 0x10: [mem 0x6003228000-0x60032280ff 64bit]
[    0.214326] pci 0000:00:1f.4: reg 0x20: [io  0xefa0-0xefbf]
[    0.214514] pci 0000:00:1f.5: [8086:a0a4] type 00 class 0x0c8000
[    0.214533] pci 0000:00:1f.5: reg 0x10: [mem 0xfe010000-0xfe010fff]
[    0.214700] pci 0000:01:00.0: [10ec:8168] type 00 class 0x020000
[    0.214719] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [io  0x4000-0x40ff]
[    0.214743] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0x52104000-0x52104fff 64bit]
[    0.214759] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x20: [mem 0x52100000-0x52103fff 64bit]
[    0.214876] pci 0000:01:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    0.214877] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[    0.215039] pci 0000:00:1d.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
[    0.215042] pci 0000:00:1d.0:   bridge window [io  0x4000-0x4fff]
[    0.215045] pci 0000:00:1d.0:   bridge window [mem 0x52100000-0x521fffff]
[    0.215382] pci 0000:02:00.0: [10ec:c822] type 00 class 0x028000
[    0.215405] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x10: [io  0x3000-0x30ff]
[    0.215435] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0x52000000-0x5200ffff 64bit]
[    0.215581] pci 0000:02:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    0.215582] pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[    0.215960] pci 0000:00:1d.1: PCI bridge to [bus 02]
[    0.215962] pci 0000:00:1d.1:   bridge window [io  0x3000-0x3fff]
[    0.215965] pci 0000:00:1d.1:   bridge window [mem 0x52000000-0x520fffff]
[    0.234181] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.DGPV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20211217/psargs-330)
[    0.234187] fbcon: Taking over console

[    0.234194] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_OFF]

[    0.234194] No Arguments are initialized for method [_OFF]

[    0.234196] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG0.PCRP._OFF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20211217/psparse-529)
[    0.234240] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[    0.234241] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[    0.234260] ACPI: EC: EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x66, EC_DATA=0x62
[    0.234261] ACPI: EC: GPE=0x6e
[    0.234261] ACPI: \_SB_.PC00.LPCB.EC0_: Boot ECDT EC initialization complete
[    0.234262] ACPI: \_SB_.PC00.LPCB.EC0_: EC: Used to handle transactions and events
[    0.234309] iommu: Default domain type: Translated 
[    0.234309] iommu: DMA domain TLB invalidation policy: lazy mode 
[    0.234309] pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: setting as boot VGA device
[    0.234309] pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: VGA device added: decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    0.234309] pci 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: bridge control possible
[    0.234309] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.234309] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.234309] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[    0.234309] ACPI: bus type USB registered
```

Any suggestions on how to fix the system?
How can I boot to the updated kernel using Secure Boot?

I'm using a HP 250 G8 laptop (Intel Tiger Lake).

Comment: Mainline kernel are not supported here. This is only a part of the log, that doesn't contain anything about e.g. Wi-Fi. Why would you install an unsupported kernel, there should be a very good reason to do it. And you can't install it with Secure Boot on. And I don't see any ACPI errors.

Comment: So how can I update the kernel?

Comment: Boot with a supported kernel using grub menu and remove the kernel that doesn't work well on your system.

Comment: Ok but how can I upgrade the kernel to 5.18 for example? And what you mean that mainline kernel are not supported here?

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't use mainline kernels. It is not a supported way to "upgrade" Ubuntu by installing mainline kernels. It can be done for a good reason, e.g. when some hardware doesn't work, or to work with some bug.

Comment: So one can not upgrade the kernel?

Comment: See kernel categories: mainline, stable, longterm https://www.kernel.org/